# About the Platonic Solids in all dimensions

Tags: reference-request, solid-geometry, polytopes, platonic-solids

I am asking about the Platonic solids in all dimensions, some reference about the proofs of many of the statements made [here](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/platonic.html).

I would like to hear about how to think about higher dimensions, mainly the solids.

I could only understand the famous "tesseract" (famous thanks to the marvel) which is a simple 4-cube or a simple ball in the maximum norm.

Comment: Everything you might possibly want to know is proved in H.S.M.Coxeter's *Regular polytopes*.

Comment: in stock! http://store.doverpublications.com/0486614808.html